# How do I add a jar to netbeans 7.3.1?

Tags: jar, ide, netbeans-7

Instructions I've found seem to be for older version of netbeans, how do I add a jar to netbeans version 7.3.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, didn't have to add it to netbeans, but to maven - edited the pom.